# AngularJs Formatter not invoked when array changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, formatter

In my sample code I have two behaviours that I can't really understand and I hope you guys can enlighten me what is going on and what I do wrong:

1. I have a formatter in the directive array-to-string that is only
   being invoked during the initialization process. When I update the
   array in my Controller with the push function the formatter is not
   being invoked. Why is that and what can I do to overcome that?
2. In the formatter function of array-to-string I extract the values of the array into a single string. After the transformation I return that string. Now why isn't the ng-model of mydir being changed into the value the formatter of array-to-string returns? It makes no sense to me since the formatter of mydir gets the result of the array-to-string formatter (I misused the formatter in the mydir directive to show what's going on wrong in my opinion)

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").directive("arrayToString", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(array) {
        console.log("formatter called");
        var text = "";
        angular.forEach(array, function(e) {
          text += e.label + ", ";
        });
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
        console.log(text);
        return text;
      });
    }
  };
});

angular.module("app").directive("mydir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      ngModel: "="
    },
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(alreadyFormattedValue) {
        scope.myString = alreadyFormattedValue;
      });
    },
    template: "<div>{{myString}}</div><div>{{ngModel}}</div>"
  }
});

angular.module("app").controller("Controller", function() {
  var _this = this;
  
  _this.myValues = [
    { label: "apple" },
    { label: "lemon" },
    { label: "pear" }
  ];
  
  _this.add = function() {
    _this.myValues.push({ label: "strawberry" });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8" data-require="angular.js@1.3.20"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <mydir ng-model="ctrl.myValues" array-to-string=""></mydir>
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.add()">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: seems this trouble with _watch_, if you change `this.myValues.push({ label: "strawberry" });` to `this.myValues = this.myValues.concat({ label: "strawberry" });` all formatter work.

Comment: Grundy, this is just great. I still don't like that the push-function doesn't work (somehow they managed to make the normal binding work, you know the {{ngModel}} gets updated) but at least I now have something that kicks on the formatters

Comment: i try investigate it a bit more, and possibly can explain in answer later :-)

Comment: This is documented. If your model is not value type you have to use angular.copy or any other approach that generates another hash for the engine detect the changes

Answer (score 0):

If go a bit deeper to source code for ngModel directive, we can find that for watch used [custom function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L860). In this function exist `if` with next condition.

```
if (modelValue !== ctrl.$modelValue &&
       // checks for NaN is needed to allow setting the model to NaN when there's an asyncValidator
       (ctrl.$modelValue === ctrl.$modelValue || modelValue === modelValue)
    )
```

So, `modelValue` just compared with `!==` and if reference not changed, to viewValue not applied neither formatters, no validators.

Simplest way - just change reference, i.e. use, for example, [*concat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function instead [*push*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
_this.myValues = _this.myValues.concat({ label: "strawberry" });
```

Sample

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").directive("arrayToString", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(array) {
        console.log("formatter called");
        var text = "";
        angular.forEach(array, function(e) {
          text += e.label + ", ";
        });
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
        console.log(text);
        return text;
      });
    }
  };
});

angular.module("app").directive("mydir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      ngModel: "="
    },
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(alreadyFormattedValue) {
        scope.myString = alreadyFormattedValue;
      });
    },
    template: "<div>{{myString}}</div><div>{{ngModel}}</div>"
  }
});

angular.module("app").controller("Controller", function() {
  var _this = this;
  
  _this.myValues = [
    { label: "apple" },
    { label: "lemon" },
    { label: "pear" }
  ];
  
  _this.add = function() {
    _this.myValues = _this.myValues.concat({ label: "strawberry" });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8" data-require="angular.js@1.3.20"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <mydir ng-model="ctrl.myValues" array-to-string=""></mydir>
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.add()">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Next variant: you can add your own `$watch` and apply formatters manually

```
scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
}, function(n) {
    var formatters = ngModelCtrl.$formatters,
        idx = formatters.length;

    var viewValue = n;
    while (idx--) {
        viewValue = formatters[idx](viewValue);
    }
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(viewValue);
});
```

Sample:

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").directive("arrayToString", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      scope.$watchCollection(function() {
        return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
      }, function(n) {
        var formatters = ngModelCtrl.$formatters,
          idx = formatters.length;

        var viewValue = n;
        while (idx--) {
          viewValue = formatters[idx](viewValue);
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(viewValue);
      });
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(array) {
        console.log("formatter called");
        var text = "";
        angular.forEach(array, function(e) {
          text += e.label + ", ";
        });
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
        console.log(text);
        return text;
      });
    }
  };
});

angular.module("app").directive("mydir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      ngModel: "="
    },
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(alreadyFormattedValue) {
        scope.myString = alreadyFormattedValue;
      });
    },
    template: "<div>{{myString}}</div><div>{{ngModel}}</div>"
  }
});

angular.module("app").controller("Controller", function() {
  var _this = this;

  _this.myValues = [{
    label: "apple"
  }, {
    label: "lemon"
  }, {
    label: "pear"
  }];

  _this.add = function() {
    _this.myValues.push({
      label: "strawberry"
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8" data-require="angular.js@1.3.20"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
  <mydir ng-model="ctrl.myValues" array-to-string=""></mydir>
  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.add()">Add</button>
</body>

</html>
```